# Magento add to cart product issue

Tags: magento-1.9, json

Getting really weird issue. Some of my products are not getting to cart.

https://www.saree.com/beige-and-navy-blue-art-silk-blouse-with-stone-work-saaabl003

while this one works

https://www.saree.com/off-white-art-silk-blouse-with-resham-embroidery-work-saaabl011

The configs of both the products are same from backend. Both the products were used to work few days ago. No changes have been made to website. No customization done in last 3 months. No server configs were changed.

When I turn on developer console, i get some json error. Can anyone please help me with this ?

The first product will start working if I change the url key value. 
The following product was having same problem, but after changing url key, it started working as normal.

sareedotcom/saaabl004 (cant put more than 2 links due to restriction )

Comment: The url key make me think it can be related to cache. Have you tried to clean block, layout and full page cache? Also do you have any errors in exception/system logs?

Comment: I have cleared all cache and and reindexed store at least 10 times. These products are 6 months old. They were working without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

After theme update, it had some bugs with SID value. 
According to developer console, json calls were not packed properly.

So I investigated everything related to login.

After changing value of use SID in front end to No, everything got sorted.

Wasted almost 15 days :(